# Animated Typing Memory Usage with Immutable Strings

Tags: animation, performance, memory

Right now I'm programming a game that has an animated typing effect typically seen in older 1980's and 90's role-playing games. An example can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/9EGWUQjrZYM?t=6m29s).

The typing effect is generated by taking a target string and rendering a substring of it each frame. The length of the substring is initially zero, but it is incremented every few hundred milliseconds. This gives the impression that the string is being *typed out*. The pseudocode would more or less look like:

```
var message = "This is some dialogue.";
var substringLength = 0;

if (someTimeHasPassed)
{
   render(message.substring(0, substringLength);
   substringLength++;
}
```

This works great, but I'm using a garbage-collected language with immutable strings. Every few milliseconds, I create a new substring on the heap. Garbage collections become very frequent and I receive memory warnings on mobile devices.

Is there a way to generate this typing effect without creating lots of strings in memory?

Comment: When engine are you using?

Comment: Have you profiled to check that the string allocations are causing the GCs? I'm skeptical - strings are not that big, and even in the constrained memory space of a mobile device I wouldn't expect your message.substring call, happening every few hundred ms (as described above), to cause GC issues. What goes on in `render()`? What does your `someTimeHasPassed` check actually look like?

Comment: @Steven The game is written in JavaScript with the Phaser library on Apache Cordova.

Comment: @ChrisMills-Price I'll try checking that now with profiling. There actually isn't any `render()` function, as Phaser uses a scene-graph setup. The string is being updated with a loop with JavaScript's `String.splice()` function. During this time, the device becomes really warm and receives memory warnings from the OS.